# Rspec - using create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In Rspec - I am trying to speed up tests by reducing the number of object persisted to the database.  I am using Factory Girl also.

Using the example below, is this created in the database?  And if so, how could this be changed not to use the database?

```
   require 'rails_helper'

describe BankingDetail do
  let(:user) {create :user}
  let(:principal){create :principal}
  let(:credit_type){create :credit_type}
  let(:security_type_1){create :security_type}
  let(:security_type_2){create :security_type, name: 'Test Working Capital'}
  let(:banking_detail) {create :banking_detail, credit_type: credit_type, bank_line: "12345.00000", bank_id: 1, principal: principal, create_user: user}

  it 'is a valid factory' do
    expect(FactoryGirl.create(:banking_detail, credit_type: credit_type, bank_line: "12345.00000", bank_id: 1, principal: principal, create_user: user )).to be_valid
  end

  it 'should not be saved when principal is empty' do
    banking_detail.principal_id = nil
    expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy
  end

  it 'should not be saved when create user is empty' do
    banking_detail.create_user_id = nil
    expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy
  end

  it 'should be able to generate a version' do
    banking_detail = build(:banking_detail, credit_type: credit_type, bank_line: "12345.00000", bank_id: 1, principal: principal, create_user: user)
    expect{banking_detail.generate_version!('update')}.to change(BankingDetailVersion, :count).by(1)
  end

  context 'validation' do
    it 'should not save when bank line is  empty ' do
      banking_detail.bank_line = nil
      expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy
    end

    it 'should not save when bank line is not in the minimum maximum currency range ' do
      banking_detail.bank_line = 1_000_000_000_000_000_0000
      expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy
    end
    it 'should not save when credit_available is not in the minimum maximum currency range ' do
      banking_detail.credit_available = 1_000_000_000_000_000_0000
      expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you add a description and example of what exactly it is that you are actually testing? It's kind of hard to rewrite a test with only unknowns.

Comment: I guess I am more looking for general testing advice, I want to speed up tests and I have hundreds of business logic tests I have inherited and want to speed up and I don't know where to start.  I upgraded to RSpec 3 but it doesnt make any different in speed.

Comment: Do you you think you could edit the question and add a different example which actually has some expectations so that it shows what kind of behavior you are testing? If you just want generic advice than it is don't touch the database when you don't need to. If you want some more concrete advise than you need to give us something to go on.

Comment: I have updated to use a model test to test banking details

Answer (score 0):

There is a `build_stubbed` method for example if you use FactoryGirl. It can speed up specs quite a bit and won't create objects to database.

Little description I quote from [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/use-factory-girls-build-stubbed-for-a-faster-test):

*build_stubbed is the younger, more hip sibling to build; it instantiates and assigns attributes just like build, but that’s where the similarities end. It makes objects look like they’ve been persisted, creates associations with the build_stubbed strategy (whereas build still uses create), and stubs out a handful of methods that interact with the database and raises if you call them. This leads to much faster tests and reduces your test dependency on a database.*

Comment: how would I use that with the example above? do I have to replace 'create' as is that active record?

Comment: I guess one way would be like this: `@jobs << build_stubbed(:job, job_number: i.to_s, job_description: desc.to_s)` but I can't test it out right now so maybe I'm missing something here.

Comment: getting this when trying it on a different one:  RuntimeError: stubbed models are not allowed to access the database

Comment: for example at this line:   expect(banking_detail.save).not_to be_truthy

Comment: Yes- as the error message says- you can't make database query opertaions on stubbed objects. As I understand it, stubbed object is basically a bunch of methods that are stubbed out to imitate a real object in db. Therefore you definitely can't say that you can use `build_stubbed` almost everywhere in your specs. Above-mentioned line is one example- if you want to test success of saving a test-object then you can't use `build_stubbed`.

Comment: Your error is explained [here](http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/useful-factory-girl-methods-part-two/) a little.